# Is it possible to access Storage Spaces from Windows 8.1 instance running under VMware Workstation?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, vmware-workstation, storage-spaces

I have a single Storage Space (2-way mirror) under Windows 8.1. The disks are in an external eSATA enclosure. It's mounted as a single drive. I'd like to access the data on the Storage Space from Windows running under VMware Workstation on Linux, or possibly VMware Fusion on OS X. Is it possible to have the VM mount and recognize the Storage Space?

My working assumption is that this is not possible because underlying OS will just see the enclosure as a set of raw disks, or possibly NTFS-formatted disks.